# Livewire - Force update view from component

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-livewire

I have a Livewire component and I want to do some async operations with it. However I could not figure out how to force refresh the update whenever I need.

To illustrate the problem, check out the example below.

Think like I'm trying to create a stop-watch. I'll click a button to start the stop-watch and everytime the $counter changes, I want to dispatch the value to my view.

```
class MyComponent extends Component {
   public $counter = 0;

   public function startTimer() {
       for ($i = 0; $i < 10; $i++) {
           $this->counter = $this->counter + 1;
           // I want to tell "send data to view/update data in view here"

           sleep(3);   
       }      
   } 
}
```

```
<button wire:click="startTimer">Start</button>
<h1>{{ $counter }}</h1>
```

This is a dummy example and I don't want to do it with polling.

Is there a way to tell to component something like `$this->updateDataInView()`?

Answer (score 1):

In Livewire you can use the magic method `$refresh` to manually refresh the view.

**Option 1, in the view**

```html
<div>
    <button wire:click="$refresh">Reload Component</button>
</div>
```

See also a [blog post](https://ryangjchandler.co.uk/articles/manually-refreshing-a-livewire-component) on this.

**Option 2, inside the component class**

```php
protected $listeners = [
    'refreshComponent' => '$refresh'
];
```

Here you need to emit the `refreshComponent` event, of course.

There is a [Github discussion](https://github.com/livewire/livewire/discussions/1023) around this topic.

Comment: I tried option 2, and tried `$this->emit('refreshComponent')` inside the for loop, however it doesn't update the data in the view for me. In the end of the loop, I receive one update (final value). Does it work for you?